# access element on a list using index

Tags: python, list

given a line of strings

```
01 02 03 04 05 
06 07 08 09 10 
.. .. .. .. ..
```

I am trying to access the 1st element, "01":

```
def ElementA (inputFile):
element_A = ""
with open(inputFile, 'r') as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:
        for i in line.split():
            element_A = i[0:2]
print(element)
```

For some reason the output is "05".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ``ElementA`` does not return any thing or is it wrongly intended, from where ``element`` is being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a little too much. If you want the first element from each line, you can just do this:

```
def ElementA (inputFile):
   element_A = ""
   with open(inputFile, 'r') as inputFile:
       for line in inputFile:
           element_A = line[0:2]
           print(element_A)
```